# Rivetsjs iteration - by using an integer instead of collection

Tags: rivets.js

According to rivetsjs docs, we can render content by iterating over a object (array) by,

```
<ul>
  <li rv-each-todo="list.todos">
    <input type="checkbox" rv-checked="todo.done">
    <span>{ todo.summary }</span>
  </li>
<ul>
```

but is there a way where I can iterate by using a single integer to indicate number of times the iteration to take place?

I mean something like this,

```
  <li rv-each="list.num_of_todos">
   ...
```

where **num_of_todos** is an integer to indicate number of iterations to take place.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "proper" way of doing it. However, you can easily mimic this using a formatter that returns an array as shown below:

---

```js
var list = {
  name: 'to do list',
  noOfToDos: 5
};
rivets.formatters.makearray = function(value) {
  var result = [];
  while (value--) {
    result.push(0)
  };
  return result;
}
rivets.bind($("ul"), { // bind rivets
  list: list
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rivets/0.7.1/rivets.bundled.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li rv-each-item="list.noOfToDos | makearray">Test</li>
  <ul>
```